# How write universal comparator which can make sorting through all necessary fields?

Tags: java, comparator

I needed to implement sorting on all fields of my class
I wrote a comparator for each field in my class. 
But I had to write a individual comparator for each field.
I think that it is not very correctly.
How write for my class  a single universal comparator which can make sorting through all fields?

My entity:

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
 .....................
```

My comparators:

```
public class UserComparatorById implements Comparator<User> {   
    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {        
       int result = (int)(user1.getId() - user2.getId());
       if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));        
       result = user1.getName().compareTo (user2.getName());
       if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));
       result = user1.getAge() - user2.getAge();
       return (result != 0) ? (int)(result/Math.abs(result)) : 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UserComparatorByName implements Comparator<User> { 
    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {            
       int result = user1.getName().compareTo (user2.getName());
       if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));
       result = (int)(user1.getId() - user2.getId());
       if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));  
       result = user1.getAge() - user2.getAge();
       return (result != 0) ? (int)(result/Math.abs(result)) : 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UserComparatorByAge implements Comparator<User> {  
    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {            
       int result = user1.getAge() - user2.getAge();
       if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));
       result = (int)(user1.getId() - user2.getId());
       if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));   
       result = user1.getName().compareTo (user2.getName());
       return (result != 0) ? (int)(result/Math.abs(result)) : 0;
    }
}
```

Sorting:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users.add(new User(5, "Frank", 28));
    users.add(new User(1, "Jorge", 19));
    users.add(new User(6, "Bill", 34));
    users.add(new User(3, "Michel", 17));
    users.add(new User(7, "Mark", 42));

    UserComparatorByName comparatorByName = new UserComparatorByName();
    Collections.sort(users, comparatorByName);

    UserComparatorByAge comparatorByAge = new UserComparatorByAge();
    Collections.sort(users, comparatorByAge);
```

Comment: Are you aware that `Comparator` can return **any** value per contract, only the sign is important? Thus `if (result != 0) return (int)(result/Math.abs(result));` can be replaced with `if (result != 0) return result`.

Comment: define `can make sorting through all fields`

Comment: I will take note of this, thank you

Answer (score 4):

One implementation per field isn't that bad, however there is a lot of duplication in your code. You should have one comparator per exactly one field. If you want to compare based on several fields but in different order, wrap *atomic* comparators (*Decorator* pattern):

```
public abstract class AbstractComparator implements Comparator<User> {
    private final AbstractComparator next;

    public AbstractComparator(AbstractComparator next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {
        int result = doCompare(user1, user2);
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return next != null? next.compare(user1, user2) : 0;
        }
    }

    public abstract int doCompare(User user1, User user2);
}
```

---

```
class ById extends AbstractComparator {
    public ById(AbstractComparator next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public int doCompare(User user1, User user2) {
        return (int) (user1.getId() - user2.getId());
    }
}
```

---

```
class ByName extends AbstractComparator {
    public ByName(AbstractComparator next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public int doCompare(User user1, User user2) {
        return user1.getName().compareTo(user2.getName());
    }
}
```

---

```
class ByAge extends AbstractComparator {
    public ByAge(AbstractComparator next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public int doCompare(User user1, User user2) {
        return user1.getAge() - user2.getAge();
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
Comparator<User> comp1 = new ById(new ByName(new ByAge(null)));
Comparator<User> comp2 = new ByAge(new ByName(new ById(null)));
```

`comp1` first sorts by `id` and if it is equal, falls back to `name` and to `age` as a last resort. The API is pretty clear.

For convenience you should place all `By*` classes as static inner classes of `User`: `User.ByName`, `User.ByAge`, etc. or maybe with some factory methods: `User.byName(User.byAge(null))`. With a help of some static imports you can echieve pleasant:

```
Collections.sort(users, byName(byAge(byId(null))));
```

Alternatively have a look at [CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) from Commons Lang.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) and [Group Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/) will help you out.