# Java: Implement Compararable but too many conditional ifs. How can I avoid them?

Tags: java, design-patterns, if-statement, comparator, comparable

I have a `list` of objects which implement `Comparable`.

I want to sort this list and that is why I used the `Comparable`.

Each object has a field, `weight` that is composed of 3 other member int variables.

The `compareTo` returns `1` for the object with the most `weight`.
The most weight is not only if the

```
weightObj1.member1 > weightObj2.member1  
weightObj1.member2 > weightObj2.member2  
weightObj1.member3 > weightObj2.member3
```

but actually is a little more complicated and I end up with code with too many conditional ifs.

If the `weightObj1.member1 > weightObj2.member1` holds then I care if `weightObj1.member2 > weightObj2.member2`.

and vice versa.

else if `weightObj1.member2 > weightObj2.member2` holds then I care if `weightObj1.member3 > weightObj2.member3` and vice versa.

Finally if `weightObj1.member3 > weightObj2.member3` holds AND if a specific condition is met then this `weightObj1` wins and vice versa

I was wondering is there a design approach for something like this?

Comment: You've told us what the "most weight" is *not*; so what *is* the most weight?  Is it if the sum of all the `weightObj1` members is greater than the sum of all the `weightObj2` members?

Comment: If you do not explain the weight algorithm it is difficult to help. Anyway, in order to keep encapsulation, you should make Weight comparable too, and simply route calls to the main object compareTo to Weight method.

Comment: I have updated OP.Is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API for `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) states:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals.

Since the values of interest are `int` values you should be able to come up with a single value that captures all comparisons and other transformations you need to compare two of your objects. Just update the single value when any of the member values change.

Answer (score 6):

You can try with `CompareToBuilder` from Apache [`commons-lang`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
   MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
   return new CompareToBuilder()
     .appendSuper(super.compareTo(o)
     .append(this.field1, myClass.field1)
     .append(this.field2, myClass.field2)
     .append(this.field3, myClass.field3)
     .toComparison();
}
```

### See also

- [How write universal comparator which can make sorting through all necessary fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087330)
- [Group Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/), [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) and [Column Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the above-mentioned Apache CompareToBuilder, but including generics support, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides ComparisonChain:

```
public int compareTo(Foo that) {
  return ComparisonChain.start()
     .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
     .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
     .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
          // you can specify comparators
     .result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using reflection, iterate over properties and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
int c1 = o1.m1 - o2.m1;
if (c1 != 0) {
    return c1;
}

int c2 = o1.m2 - o2.m2;
if (c2 != 0) {
    return c2;
}

return o1.m3 - o2.m3;
```

because comparable shall not just return -1, 0 or 1. It can return any integer value and only the sign is considered.